# Artifactory 7.10.x 404 not found error over https

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-insights

I have installed JFrog Community Edition 7.10.x, which is running on Tomcat, and it's working fine over http://art.com/8082.

To enable SSL I have applied the below settings in my system.yaml file, but when I try to access it via https://art.com:8082, it gives a 404 not found error

```
artifactory:
    tomcat:
        httpsConnector:
            enabled: true
            port: 8082
            certificateFile: "certificate path"
            certificateKeyFile: "key path"
```

How can I enable SSL on Artifactory 7 with tomcat?

Comment: Why port 8082 and not the standard 443?

Comment: Yes used port standard port 443   as well still gives same error.

Comment: Any suggestion would be helpful

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Artifactory, so the port discrepancy was the extent of my suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable TLS through the access micro service.

See this article: https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-enable-tls-within-the-jfrog-platform/artifactory-how-to-enable-tls-within-the-jfrog-platform and this documentation https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/step-1-enable-tls-in-the-jfrog-platform

In short you need to
Set tls: true in access.config.yml, with:

1. $ cd $JFROG_HOME/artifactory/var/etc/access
2. mv access.config.latest.yml access.config.import.yml.
3. Add the below snippet to access.config.import.yml.

   security:
   tls: true
4. Restart the Artifactory node.

By default this will generate Artifactory self signed certs.
If you wish to use your own certificates then follow the instructions here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/option-2-provide-your-own-signed-certificate

Please make sure your certificates meet the prerequisites here: https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/prerequisites-for-custom-tls-certificate

My final recommendation is you instead set up Nginx to work as a reverse proxy in front of Artifactory and set up TLS termination there. This is much much easier, (you can do this on the same machine and Artifactory can generate a snippet for you to add to Nginx Conf). This is the recommended approach.